# Printing Armstrong Numbers from a Range in a For Loop as an Array *Python*

Tags: python

I'm trying to print armstrong values from a specified range in an array style format.
My current code is as below:

```
def main():


#Low and high set the bounds for the loop
low = 100

high = 499


#start the for loop for num in the range initialized
for num in range(low, high +1):

    #gets the exponent for each number
    ind_num = len(str(num))
   
    #initializes the addition of each number
    add = 0
   
    # sets x equal to num so we can check if the number is armstrong or not
    x = num

    
    #calculates the armstrong
    while x > 0:
        digit = x % 10
       
        add += digit ** ind_num

        x //= 10

    if num ==  add:
       
       print(num)
       





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output comes out to be:

```
153
370
371
407
```

and I want it to be:  `[153, 370, 371, 407]`
I'm probably thinking too hard on how to make the integers that come out of the for loop arrange as an array, but so far changing them to strings and appending them with a separate defined array variable did not work.

Comment: What didn't work **exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `print(num)` with `yield num` your function will be a generator of armstrong numbers. Make `low` and `high` parameters and you end up with a versatile function:

```
def armstrong(low, high):
    for num in range(low, high +1):
        ind_num = len(str(num))
        add = 0
        x = num
        while x > 0:
            digit = x % 10       
            add += digit ** ind_num
            x //= 10
        if num == add:
            yield num


result = list(armstrong(100, 499))
print(result)
```

Comment: This makes much more sense just in case I would need to change the parameters of high and low. I didn't think about using a separate function with set parameters for calculating armstrong and I can call results and print by using my main function. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as adding the items to a list and then printing the list.

At the start of your `main()` function add in a variable `output = []`. Then in your `if` statement `if num == add:`, instead of calling `print` do `output.append(num)`. Then at the end of your `main()` function print the list, `print(output)`.

Comment: I tried this before but called print within the if statement which gave me the Armstrong in descending order, but in brackets which is almost the same as my original output. The output this gives me is a single empty bracket.